# Использовать event.target как JQuery объект

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    $('#tab-1').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function (e) {
        var $element = $(e.target);
        console.log($element);
    });
```

Но тут возвращается обычный HTML, как получить объект? Что бы работать с jquery

Вот ошибка при вызове: `$element.attr('id');`

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr is not a function
```

Comment: попробуйте e.target.getAttribute('id') или просто e.target.id, тоже должно работать

Comment: @Darth так то работает, но вопрос в другом, почему с jquery не выходит?

Comment: Потому-что jQuery. С какой проблемой я ни сталкивался в $.сделать_всё_как_надо() , любая из них решалась, если сделать всё на нативном js